# How to get rid of whitespace in a ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, whitespace

I'm preparing a figure for a publication. I'm omitting the x label by setting `xlab("")`, however ggplot2 produces a whitespace instead of completely removing the label. How can I get rid of the whitespace (marked by red rectangle in the plot below)?

[image]

The full code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Celltype, y=Mean, fill=factor(Dose), label=p.stars)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9), aes(group=Dose)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SEM, ymax = Mean + SEM), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Mean + SEM), size = 5, position = position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust = .5, vjust = -1) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Concentration") +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "Dose") +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `theme()` to remove space allocated for the x axis title. When you set `xlab("")` there is still space made for this title.

```
+ theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: This doesn't actually remove the white space, whereas the `plot.margin` solution does (albeit in a clumsy and plot-specific way).

Comment: @JackWasey This solution removes space allocated for the title and leaves some space between axis labels and plot bottom. To remove all space, yes, you have to use also `plot.margin`. But question was have to remove whitespace of axis title.

Comment: sorry, you're right. xlab(NULL) appears to be identical result as Hadley writes.

Comment: For a plot I'm working on, adding `title = element_blank()` appeared to help with whitespace on top and bottom. My code: `+ theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), title = element_blank())`

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `plot.margin`?

```
library(grid)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Celltype, y=Mean, fill=factor(Dose), label=p.stars)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9), aes(group=Dose)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SEM, ymax = Mean + SEM), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Mean + SEM), size = 5, position = position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust = .5, vjust = -1) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Concentration") +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "Dose") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "cm")) # ("left", "right", "bottom", "top")
```

Comment: This may have changed since @lukeA's answer, but it appears that the parameters of the plot.margins call respectively affect 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
savepdf <- function(file, width=16, height=10) {
            fname <- paste("figures/",file,".pdf",sep="") 
            pdf(fname, width=width/2.54, height=height/2.54, 
                 pointsize=10)
            par(mgp=c(2.2,0.45,0), tcl=-0.4, mar=c(3.3,3.6,1.1,1.1))
}
```

You can also crop the white space in the resulting pdf file once created.  In Unix, the system command is:

```
pdfcrop filename.pdf filename.pdf
```

pdfcrop does work on Mac provided the standard LaTeX distribution (Mactex or texlive) is installed. Of course, this command can be executed in R as follows:

```
system(paste("pdfcrop", filename, filename))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also set x = NULL in labs()

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Celltype, y=Mean, fill=factor(Dose), label=p.stars)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9), aes(group=Dose)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SEM, ymax = Mean + SEM), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Mean + SEM), size = 5, position = position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust = .5, vjust = -1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Concentration") +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "Dose") +
  theme_bw()
```