# Can one automatically remove unnecessary whitespace/margin in choroplethr ggplot2 plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, choroplethr

There are many questions that deal with removing whitespace from standard ggplot2 plots, like [barplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576745/how-to-get-rid-of-whitespace-in-a-ggplot2-plot). However, there is currently no question about **choroplethr**-based ggplot2 plots. I did not find any questions about other non-standard plots either, so I ask.

I am mapping data for [Argentinian first-level administrative divisions (provinces)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_of_Argentina). First load libraries and example data:

```
library(ggplot2); library(grid); library(choroplethr); library(choroplethrAdmin1)
d_argentina_admin1 = 
structure(list(country = c("argentina", "argentina", "argentina", 
"argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", 
"argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", 
"argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", 
"argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", "argentina", 
"argentina"), region = c("ciudad autonoma de buenos aires", "provincia de buenos aires", 
"provincia de catamarca", "provincia de cordoba", "provincia de corrientes", 
"provincia de entre rios", "provincia de formosa", "provincia de jujuy", 
"provincia de la pampa", "provincia de la rioja", "provincia de mendoza", 
"provincia de misiones", "provincia de rio negro", "provincia de salta", 
"provincia de san juan", "provincia de san luis", "provincia de santa cruz", 
"provincia de santa fe", "provincia de santiago del estero", 
"provincia de tierra del fuego, antartida e islas del atlantico sur", 
"provincia de tucuman", "provincia del chaco", "provincia del chubut", 
"provincia del neuquen"), region_short = c("ciudad autonoma de buenos aires", 
"buenos aires", "catamarca", "cordoba", "corrientes", "entre rios", 
"formosa", "jujuy", "la pampa", "la rioja", "mendoza", "misiones", 
"rio negro", "salta", "san juan", "san luis", "santa cruz", "santa fe", 
"santiago del estero", "tierra del fuego, antartida e islas del atlantico sur", 
"tucuman", "chaco", "chubut", "neuquen"), CA = c(1.68523081351625, 
0.12549520300237, -1.27397814948309, 0.455533000767044, -0.852755464371651, 
0.311078868096833, -1.15435688398305, -0.731142526555172, 1.10745473359446, 
-1.17376627430079, 0.410907812201062, -0.559784594595219, 0.752534373004307, 
-0.10532704793929, -0.534917391396886, 0.565419267663713, 0.550492884041435, 
0.775972211209032, -1.35483468421443, 0.243461376532096, -0.456931964639015, 
-1.21548156415082, -0.184277139940435, 2.61397314194124), S = c(2.28055681849635, 
0.886904398431874, -0.0336697376305896, 0.795396060124547, -1.10055353978519, 
0.215269561474404, -1.91800141017787, -0.85287131899651, 0.602260636644222, 
0.107582135770333, 0.509706470343261, -1.34372858962124, 0.266348607390528, 
-0.813557146573346, 0.178982808194874, 0.387580775513218, 0.836845928452549, 
0.633109400616697, -1.19041212503163, 1.10688354366868, -0.180773498720898, 
-1.91244609716818, 0.0289904264255843, 0.50959589215834), European_pct = c(NA, 
79L, 55L, 70L, 56L, 70L, 58L, 45L, 72L, 55L, 68L, 65L, 63L, 45L, 
60L, 67L, 63L, 76L, 55L, 63L, 63L, 58L, 63L, 63L), HDI2011 = c(0.889, 
0.838, 0.836, 0.862, 0.828, 0.839, 0.806, 0.829, 0.864, 0.834, 
0.852, 0.817, 0.851, 0.832, 0.825, 0.828, 0.873, 0.846, 0.807, 
0.88, 0.843, 0.807, 0.848, 0.855), HDI1996 = c(0.854, 0.769, 
0.766, 0.776, 0.766, 0.763, 0.739, 0.743, 0.782, 0.76, 0.782, 
0.747, 0.77699999999999, 0.756, 0.767, 0.762, 0.791, 0.777, 0.745, 
0.804, 0.77, 0.765, 0.777, 0.784), Latitude = c(34.6, 34.92, 
28.47, 31.42, 27.47, 31.74, 26.19, 24.19, 36.62, 29.41, 32.89, 
27.36, 40.81, 24.78, 31.54, 33.3, 51.62, 31.61, 27.78, 54.8, 
26.81, 27.45, 43.3, 38.95), Mean.C = c(18.1, 15.8, 20.5, 17.63, 
21.1, 18, 22.1, 18.7, 15.5, 20.1, 16.7, 21.3, 14.2, 16.5, 17.9, 
17.2, 7.6, 18.5, 20.4, 5.7, 19.3, 21, 13.6, 14.5), Knoema_name = c("Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires", 
"Buenos Aires", "Catamarca", "Córdoba", "Corrientes", "Entre Ríos", 
"Formosa", "Jujuy", "La Pampa", "La Rioja", "Mendoza", "Misiones", 
"Río Negro", "Salta", "San Juan", "San Luis", "Santa Cruz", "Santa Fe", 
"Santiago del Estero", "Tierra del Fuego", "Tucumán", "Chaco", 
"Chubut", "Neuquén"), long = c(-58.4087168822226, -60.4520279200146, 
-67.0033502110092, -63.6371590458406, -57.5922837730968, -59.1929261299057, 
-59.9002069633236, -65.6846836561529, -66.0781718361702, -67.8240418774711, 
-68.9698150834006, -54.6502325454809, -67.7111354201418, -65.5153259609209, 
-68.9777591351386, -66.3059831227416, -69.6838127357142, -60.6945670435963, 
-64.3580773677863, -65.8132823586689, -65.4186581044413, -59.9636744025983, 
-67.6203412779368, -70.5435477557748), lat = c(-34.6301055975446, 
-37.2961720341364, -27.4440629216902, -31.7921585910377, -28.7753987205406, 
-32.1078433856807, -25.095300376526, -23.4789231673989, -38.0265724152956, 
-29.3771688411262, -34.257024768382, -26.8538125248083, -40.047744111783, 
-24.0730809995991, -30.6947781801545, -33.0413870848178, -49.2068318102752, 
-31.675607181458, -28.0818062780313, -54.5269245027309, -27.015093754783, 
-25.8734309245111, -43.9885104650552, -38.5793873300344), value = c(18.1, 
15.8, 20.5, 17.63, 21.1, 18, 22.1, 18.7, 15.5, 20.1, 16.7, 21.3, 
14.2, 16.5, 17.9, 17.2, 7.6, 18.5, 20.4, 5.7, 19.3, 21, 13.6, 
14.5)), .Names = c("country", "region", "region_short", "CA", 
"S", "European_pct", "HDI2011", "HDI1996", "Latitude", "Mean.C", 
"Knoema_name", "long", "lat", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), class = "data.frame")
```

We can plot the temperature data using the following code:

```
d_argentina_admin1$value = d_argentina_admin1$Mean.C
admin1_choropleth(country.name = "argentina", 
                  df           = d_argentina_admin1, 
                  #title        = "2010 Japan Population Estimates", 
                  legend       = "Mean temperature (C)", 
                  num_colors   = 1) +
  geom_text(data = d_argentina_admin1, aes(long, lat, label = Knoema_name, group = NULL), size = 2.5)
ggplot("map_temp.png")
```

The first line is because this function always wants to use the `value` column, so one has to move data into that column instead of specifying the column. We save it using `ggsave` and it looks like this:

[image]

The mean temperatures are higher in the north as expected.

It can be seen (using mouse hover) that there is a lot of whitespace around the map which one would like to remove. One can remove it manually by tinkering with the `ggsave` parameters:

```
ggsave("figures/map_temp2.png", width = 5, height = 7)
```

[image]

But there should be an automatic method to do this. I tried adding `0` plot margins as suggested in other questions, but it had no effect.

```
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))
```

How does one automatically remove whitespace/margins from this type of ggplot2 plot?